# adding iPad splitviewcontroller to universal app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, universal

When my app starts on an iPad I want to use a totally different xib and will probably use different view controllers for most everything. My app for iPhone is setup to use a tabbarcontroller but I want the app to start with a splitviewcontroller when on iPad.

Here's the code

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSLog(@"ipad");
        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"iPhone");
        self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

This works fine for the iPhone but when I start it on an iPad the log says.
2011-12-06 13:52:30.984 MA Mobile[38349:fe03] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application

I have created a separate nib that is identical to the mainwindow.xib except it has a splitviewcontroller that is linked to the app delegate instead of a tabbarcontroller.

UPDATE SOLVED: My targets iPad Main Interface was not specified...

However it now appears that the detail view is totally covering the entire view (like it's not a split view but just a tableview with no navigation controller) maybe I'm missing something else...

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer for people who stumble across this in the future.